# Unrecognized selector sent to class when running a react-native app as a view controller in another app

Tags: objective-c, swift, react-native

We have a react-native app that we develop as a standalone app and then we have a pod that exports the app with a native entry point. Part of our app uses `react-native-awesome-card-io` which works fine when we run the the app as a standalone piece (metro bundler). We use cocoa pods to manage the dependencies that react-native link usually does for us. We were using `react-native: 57.8` but had to upgrade to `59.0` in order to be able to integrate our plugin into android apps without having to add filtering for 32/64 bit. Anyways we have an example app that just has a button and when the button is pressed, the action takes the view controller we created and `presentModalViewController` is triggered. The issue came up after we upgraded react-native, when we call the `scanCard` function on press in our react-native js, The following error comes up

It worked fine previously and it works if we run the app as a standalone react-native app but when we integrate it, the issue comes up. Here is how we `instantiate` the react-native plugin.

NOTE: it fails for both our objective-c and swift example consumer apps. I haven't found anything online.

How we load our viewcontroller in our sample app

```
- (IBAction)launchPaciolanSDKAction:(UIButton *)sender {
printf("Launching PaciolanSDK ...");
UIViewController *viewController = nil;
viewController = [[PaciolanSDKViewController alloc] initWithString::""];
[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

}

Error:

```
Exception 'Please add -ObjC to 'Other Linker Flags' in your project settings. (+[NSObject testForObjCLinkerFlag]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1dbbd7eb0)' was thrown while invoking scanCard on target CardIOModule with params (
        {
        hideCardIOLogo = 1;
        requireCardholderName = 1;
        suppressManualEntry = 1;
        usePaypalActionbarIcon = 0;
    },
    3544,
    3545
)
callstack: (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001a1cf5ebc <redacted> + 252
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001a0ec5a50 objc_exception_throw + 56
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001a1bfc484 <redacted> + 0
    3   RNAwesomeCardIO                     0x000000010385bf6c -[CardIOPaymentViewController initWithPaymentDelegate:scanningEnabled:] + 660
    4   RNAwesomeCardIO                     0x00000001038598bc -[RCTCardIOModule scanCard:resolver:rejecter:] + 236
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001a1cfd610 <redacted> + 144
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001a1bdb340 <redacted> + 292
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001a1bdbf24 <redacted> + 60
    8   React                               0x0000000103ec3d10 -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] + 2064
    9   React                               0x0000000103ecfe2c _ZN8facebook5reactL11invokeInnerEP9RCTBridgeP13RCTModuleDatajRKN5folly7dynamicE + 664
    10  React                               0x0000000103ecf99c _ZZN8facebook5react15RCTNativeModule6invokeEjON5folly7dynamicEiENK3$_0clEv + 144
    11  React                               0x0000000103ecf900 ___ZN8facebook5react15RCTNativeModule6invokeEjON5folly7dynamicEi_block_invoke + 28
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010494f824 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000104950dc8 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010495ea78 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1360
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001a1c85ce4 <redacted> + 12
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001a1c80bac <redacted> + 1964
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001a1c800e0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001a3ef9584 GSEventRunModal + 100
    19  UIKitCore                           0x00000001cefe0c00 UIApplicationMain + 212
    20  sample                              0x0000000102f0e1fc main + 124
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001a173ebb4 <redacted> + 4
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out your parameters and headers that you are sending to api.This error mostly occur when we send wrong parameters.